# Bash script for tar menu, syntax errors in case conditionals

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script that echos a menu from which a user can archive , extract and update files. I keep getting syntax errors however in my case conditionals, i've only recently started bash regex and other linux tools so i'm a bit muddled syntactically, could someone point out the right syntax to use for **conditionals in **the case structure**** for this example ?
here's some of the code i have so far:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Today's date is $(date)"
    echo "The current directory $(pwd)"
    echo -e "A full list of contents follows: $(ls -R)\n"

    echo -e "\n       Archive Menu\n"
    echo "  a.   Archive a file or directory."
    echo "  b.   Extract a file or directory from an archive."
    echo "  c.   Update archive of current directory based on timestamp."
    echo -e "   d.   Exit.\n"
    read -p "Enter a, b, c, or d: " answer
    echo
    #
    case "$answer" in
a)
    read -p "Please enter full path to the file you wish to archive: " path
    read -p "Please enter destination for the archived file (leave empty for current drectory)" dest 
    if [[ "$dest" == null]] ;
        then 
            tar -cvf $path
            tar -tvf $path
            exit 0
        fi;
    if [[ "dest" == ""]];
        then 
            tar -cvf $path $dest
            tar -tvf $path 
            exit 0
        fi;
    ;;
b)
    read -p "Please enter full path to the file you wish to extract: " path 
    read -p "Please enter destination for extracted file (leave empty for current directory)" dest
    if [ "$dest" == null]
        then 
            tar -xvf $path
            tar -tvf $path 
            exit 0
        fi
    if [ "$dest" == ""]
        then
            tar -xvf $path $dest
            tar -tvf $path
            exit 0
        fi
    ;;
c)
   esac
```

some of the error messages i've been getting are:

```
   metar.sh:line 18: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token';'
   metar.sh:line 18: syntax error near ';'
   metar.sh:line 18 '               if[[ "$dest == null]] ;'
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the error messages you're getting?  That will let us pinpoint your problems without having to plough through the entire script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space before your closing brackets on "if" statements, i.e.

```
if [[ "$x" == "$y" ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the space before the `]]` it should look like this:

```
if [[ "$dest" == null  ]]
then 
    tar -cvf $path
    tar -tvf $path
    exit 0
fi
```

Or this (now having the `then` in the same line as the `if` - separated by a `;`):

```
if [[ "$dest" == null  ]] ; then 
    tar -cvf $path
    tar -tvf $path
    exit 0
fi
```